# Proving pointwise limit of this sequence of differentiable functions is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ with each $f_{n}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable and $f_{n}(0)=0$ and also $|f'_{n}(x)| \leq 2$ for all $n$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)=g(x)$$ for all $x$. Show that $g$ is continuous.

By an application of the Mean value theorem, I have been able to show that for arbitrary $f_{n}$ and arbitrary $x$, that $$|f_{n}(x)| \leq |f'_{n}(t)||x|$$ for some $t \in (0, x)$.

By assumption that the derivatives are uniformly bounded by $2$, we get that $|f_{n}(x)| \leq 2|x|$.

At this point, I want to argue that this sequence of functions is pointwise equicontinuous (by using the assumption of pointwise convergence). Assuming this, the idea then is to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma$-compact to get uniform convergence (on all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$) to establish continuity of the limit function. I'm not yet entirely certain about this approach, but I figure I should post more than just the question statement. If someone has a better approach, I welcome it.

Comment: $\lim f_n(x)=g\Rightarrow \exists N, s.t. |g(x)-f_N(x)|\le\epsilon/3$,

$|f_N(x)-f_N(y)|\le2|x-y|$,

Thus, $|g(x)-g(y)|\le|g(x)-f_N(x)|+|f_N(x)-f_N(y)|+|f_N(y)-g(y)|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this point, I want to argue that this sequence of functions is pointwise equicontinuous

That's not a bad idea. But here is an even better one: the family $\{ f_n\}$ is *equilipschitz*, we have

$$\lvert f_n(x) - f_n(y)\rvert \leqslant 2 \cdot \lvert x-y\rvert$$

for all $n,x,y$.

Comment: D'oh. I knew there was something important I was overlooking.